# Association rule using Python mlxtend

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of data among which I want to find the association. I have found the frequent itemset using -

```
frequent_itemsets = apriori(df, min_support=0.01, use_colnames=True)
```

Which is giving the frequent itemset as -

```
        support  itemsets
0      0.020438  [AUCKLAND]
1      0.015320  [Adelaide]
2      0.043066  [Auckland]
....
```

I require to find the confidence. I have used association rule function as -

```
aa = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="confidence", min_threshold=0.001)
```

But with this I am getting a Blank Table with only the column names.

Answer (score 0):

`records = []

for i in range(0, 7501):

    records.append([str(store_data.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, 20)])
association_rules = apriori(records, min_support=0.0045, min_confidence=0.2, min_lift=3, min_length=2)`

> i think you code should be something like this you shouldn't pass the frequent_itemsets in case of association rule to apply as it works for you data separately rather you should use the appended name as i have used records in my case. i hope you might get some idea.